# Why does Drools validate all other rules when using an Agenda Filter to fire a specifc rule?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, drools

I have a whole bunch of rules and I am trying to write some unit tests for them. In my tests, I am using this:

```
int rulesFired = kSession.fireAllRules(new RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter("rule name 1"));
```

The thing I have noticed is that although the amount of rules fired returned is 1, Drools still tries to validate against any other rule where the conditions are met. I sometimes receive error messages from other rules that are not defined in my rule name equals agenda filter because the conditions match based on what I am inserting in my kSession for the unit test.

For example I have:

```
rule "test1"
    when
        $var : Map(this["key"] == "gold")
    then
        do something
    end

rule "test2"
    when
        $var : Map(this["key"] == "gold" && this["other"] == "silver")
    then
        do something
    end
```

and in my test for rule1 I have a map with just "key". When I run the test with a filter for "test1", I will receive a null pointer because I do not have a value for "other" in my map, even though the rule I am filtering for does not care about "other"

Why does this happen? I can't find any documentation on it anywhere. It's as if Drools has to validate all the rules and syntax in my DRL file before filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for evaluating rule conditions results from a combination of all rules, possibly combining identical conditions or parts of conditions such as patterns or constraints in a way that reduces the overall effort. Thus, there is no way the *evaluation* of conditions of individual rules can be suppressed at runtime.

Comment: thank you. I take it this is not documented anywhere, but can be seen in the source classes responsible for evaluating the rules as a whole.

Comment: The way Rete and its refinement work is documented. That agenda filters only affect rule firing is a corollary.

Comment: @Seephor is there a way If want to achieve this . As it is throwing Exception for having different columns.

Comment: @Neetika You should ask a new question, explaining in detail where your problem is. Your comment here isn't really elucidating.

Comment: @laune Thanks . Actually I was having the same issue ... resolve it by using more conditions in drl file .

Answer (score 0):

You can put the rules in different packages, then load them through different KieSession.